# Create impala table and add data using java

Tags: java, apache, hive, cloudera, impala

I am trying to create an impala table and add data into it using java.

1.) How should I create connection for impala?

2.) Can I create an impala table directly or should I create a hive table and access it using impala?

A java program or code snippets will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **impala jdbc driver.**

Refer the following [link](https://github.com/onefoursix/Cloudera-Impala-JDBC-Example/blob/impala-cdh-5.1.0/src/main/java/com/cloudera/example/ClouderaImpalaJdbcExample.java) , this has a sample code for the impala connection using the jdbc driver.

For creating a table in impala you could pass it as a query, neednot do it in hive. In case you add/create a table in hive then you need to invalidate metadata in impala so as to reflect the table details in impala.